# how to use awk with a space as a seperater

Tags: batch-file, awk

I want to remove the DeviceName: + space from the results

```
C:\>sample.exe | grep DeviceName | awk -F "(: )" "{print $0}"
DeviceName: Roger M's iPhone
```

This command works just fine but when i add it in a batch file the result is only Roger.

```
C:\>sample.exe | grep DeviceName | awk -F "(: )" "{print $2}"
Roger M's iPhone

for /f "tokens=1 " %%a in ('C:\sample.exe ^| grep DeviceName ^| awk -F "(: )" "{print $2}"') do set NAME=%%a
echo %name%
Roger
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work with `for /f "tokens=*"` instead of `for /f "tokens=1"`, read about tokens in [`For /F` loop description](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html).

Next code snippet could work as well (override the 1st token `%%a`, take `%%b`):

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('C:\sample.exe ^| grep DeviceName') do set NAME=%%b
echo %name%
```

Another approach: [Variable Edit/Replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('C:\sample.exe ^| grep DeviceName') do set NAME=%%a
echo %name:DeviceName: =%
```

Example:

```
d:\bat> set "_name=DeviceName: Roger M's iPhone"

d:\bat> echo %_name%
DeviceName: Roger M's iPhone

d:\bat> echo %_name:DeviceName: =%
Roger M's iPhone

d:\bat>
```

Comment: Thanks,  

tokens=n     The numbered items to  read from each line 
                   (default = 1

tokens=* will cause all items on each line to be processed

tokens=3* will process the third token and the 4th + all subsequent items, this can also be written as tokens=3,*

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using gnu tools:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%a in (
  'C:\sample.exe ^|findstr /i "^DeviceName:"'
) do set "Name=%%b"
echo %Name%
```

This works because successive delims are counted as one and tokens=1* gets the remainder of the line after the `tokens=:`